# redhat 9 persist default gateway

Tags: rhel, routing, iproute

We changed the IP addresses of our RedHat 9 system that controls a conveyor/sorter system. When originally installed many years ago someone chose 192.0.0.10 as the IP! But for some reason it defaults to the original gateway and routing tables after every reboot. It works *before* reboot when I use ip route commands. I then edited various config files (see below). Here is the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux *server_name* 2.4.27-adeos #3 Wed Apr 20 14:19:08 CDT 2005 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 192.168.141.247
nameserver 192.168.141.249
domain nv.xxx.com
```

`cat /etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=*server_name*
GATEWAY=192.168.141.254
```

`cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
BROADCAST=192.168.141.255
IPADDR=192.168.141.130
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.141.0
GATEWAY=192.168.141.254
```

`cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`:

```
default via 192.168.141.254 dev eth0
```

After reboot, `traceroute` shows:

```
[root@*server_name* network-scripts]# traceroute 192.168.143.253
traceroute to 192.168.143.253 (192.168.143.253), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  192.0.0.10 (192.0.0.10)  2997.268 ms !H  2993.543 ms !H  2999.993 ms !H
```

`ip route` output after reboot:

```
192.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  scope link
192.168.141.0/24 dev eth0  scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
default via 192.0.0.254 dev eth0
```

I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: Redhat 9? That's been EOL for over 10 years.

Comment: Did you try to simply run a recursive grep  tot find that IP  , I.e.  `grep -R 192.0.0.10 /etc`?

Comment: There should be some 'route' script under `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/rc3.d`.

Comment: @jordanm This system is communicating with GE Fanuc controls via an ISA GPIB. We have neither the time or the skills to upgrade that software and, it works, so...

Comment: @HBruijn yes, the only files it shows up in are the old ones:
`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.org:IPADDR=192.0.0.10`
`/etc/hosts.org:192.0.0.10   *server_name*`

Comment: @ludiegu I don't see anything named 'route' but there is an 'iptables'. Do you think that could be it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the route except indirectly;  the problem is that eth0 is still getting its old IP address, and not just the route.

1) be CAREFUL with simply renaming files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/{ifcfg/route}-* :  the routine to find and load interfaces is only very dumb, and will try to bring up eth0.org as a valid interface!  Dont' clutter things up with old file cruft around, but this is an added surprise maybe.  Kill those, bounce the box, see if it changes?

2) check where that GATEWAY is being picked up.  I think it's best to have it in /etc/sysconfig/network, but that's nothing to worry about yet.